# Date validation - ngbDatepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, validation, date, jhipster

I have an Angular 4 app generated by JHipster with old bootstrap.

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.28"
```

I installed ng2-validation so I would be able to validate dates (for example validate if the user is an adult when registering (by his birth date) or validate if a start date and closing date values are okay).
Unfortunately, ngbDatepicker returns an Object, while ng2-validation expects a 'yyyy-MM-dd' string or (probably - haven't tried it) a Date object as its input. That's why the following code doesn't work:

```
<input #birthDate="ngModel" id="field_birthDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" ngbDatepicker #birthDateDp="ngbDatepicker [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.birthDate" required [maxDate]="maxBirthDate"/>
```

I was thinking about getting another datepicker, but I'm afraid that it wouldn't look well with the other bootstrap inputs.
Is there any workaround to that problem? How can I validate the dates using the ngbDatepicker I have now?

Comment: Why do you say super old? ng-bootstrap is currently at v1.0.0-beta.5 so 4 months old. Have you tried to upgrade it?

Comment: Okay, sorry for that expression - but it is older than the newest one :) The datepicker in the newer version has more possibilities (as far as I know), but unfortunately I can't upgrade to beta.

Comment: Why? If there are issues, you could fix them and even contribute back to JHipster.

Comment: I need to finish and hand in the project very soon and I'm not sure what consequences will the upgrade have - I can't take any risks at this point.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade JHipster? Current version uses latest ngBootstrap

Comment: Just try running `jhipster upgrade` or `yo jhipster upgrade` if you're using a super old version of JHipster. Doc at http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: Thank you, I will try that! And thanks for the amazing job on JHipster, made my life so much easier this semester :)

Comment: what about validate: ''+registerAccount.birthDate.year+'-'+(registerAccount.birthDate.month+1)+'-'+registerAccount.birthDate.day ?